# How to get value HTML data attribute to a modal form?

Tags: html, css

I've done plenty of web work in the past, but times are changing and some markup that just landed on my desk has some functionality I don't understand but need to modify.

There is an icon used to create a new record which looks like this...

```
<span class="fa fa-plus-square large-icon-black" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRole"></span>
```

And there is a DIV which contains a form and is displayed in a modal fashion.  It looks a bit like this...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addRole" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

I'm sure there is a library added to the project (Bootstrap maybe??) which magically make the above work without any specific javascript written for it.

The problem is that there can be several icons meant to create new records but have some different key values.  For example, I want to change the icons to look like this...

```
<span class="fa fa-plus-square large-icon-black" data-param="123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRole"></span>
<span class="fa fa-plus-square large-icon-black" data-param="456" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addRole"></span>
```

In the modal div there is a form and I need to be able to set the value equal to the data-param of the clicked icon.

```
// ... inside modal div and form
<input type="hidden" value="???"> // <--- how to equal clicked data-param
```

**NOTE!** I know how to do this if I used javascript to make the onclick event for the icons.  But since there is currently no javascript specifically written to launch the modal form I am trying to figure out if there is a proper way.  I'd rather not have to change the behavior of the modal forms.

Comment: Have a look at how the folks from bootstrap do it: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target  - it sounds like a bit of JS is still required for this case

Comment: Side note in case you've been out of the loop on this - your icons are coming from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ (they're an actual font, not images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think even you know that escaping JavaScript completely is not an option here. Since invoking of modal is completely custom JavaScript free, let's add our code when this Bootstrap modal is invoked.

```
$('#addRole').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Getting the caller element data
  var caller = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var param = $(caller).data('param');

  // Assignment
  $(input, $(this)).val(param);
});
```

Comment: I suspected, but didn't know.  I was surprised there was this much going on without custom javascript so I wouldn't have been surprised if there was a solution for this also.